# Jackson is unable to parse an ISO_INSTANT example from its documentation

Tags: jackson

Im using jackson 2.9.7, running

```
new ObjectMapper().findAndRegisterModules().readValue("2011-12-03T10:15:30Z", Instant.class)
```

Leads to an exception
`Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)): Expected space separating root-level values`, but the format should be correct due to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT

From what I can tell, it expects a timestamp(`8175812123` is correctly parsed to `2229-01-30T10:55:23Z`)

Comment: Have you tried `mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);`

Comment: @Franjavi yes I did